# Record methods and parameters called in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Assume I have jQuery with several plugins loaded.

I run some code like this:

```
$('someSelector').someMethod('someParam', 'someOtherParam');
$('someOtherSelector').someOtherMethod('anotherParam');
$('anotherSelector').anotherMethodWhichMayOrMayNotBeAPlugin();
```

I'd like to write a hook to jQuery in order to record a structure in which I will hold:

- What selector was used
- Which method was called
- What arguments did it get

I know I can override both `$()` to catch selectors and I can add methods to jQuery (by writing plugins), but I'm not entirely sure how to get method's name and parameters while avoiding breaking the existing functionality of jQuery and its plugins.

Performance is not very important for this one, so any dynamic way to do it is also fine.

Comment: Detecting selectors and usage of $() would be fairly easy, it's other methods and plugins that pose a problem here. I'm curious if anyone will come up with some idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate over all the functions in `$.fn` and replace each one of them with your own function.

That function, in turn, can log the selector of the jQuery object it's called on and the arguments it received, then call the original function.

Something like:

```
$.each($.fn, function(key, func) {
    if ($.isFunction(func)) {
        $.fn[key] = function() {
            console.log("Method '" + key + "' was called");
            console.log("  on selector '" + this.selector + "'");
            console.log("  with arguments: " + arguments);
            return func.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll have to test it first before I accept it, but it looks promising and very simple (so it should be easy to debug), nice solution.